# Android JSONObject to ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, json

I'm having a problem here, I'm totally new at this.

What i try to do is pass a JSONObject to my adapter and inside my adapter create all rows for that ListView

This is my code:

```
    private static final String TAG_OS = "android";

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        try {

            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
            if (jArray != null) {
                for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

            menu_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.menu_list);

                MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(MainActivity.this, new ArrayList[] {listdata} );
                menu_list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

My adapter is this one:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList[] values;
public MenuAdapter(Context context,ArrayList[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.menu_main, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_main, parent, false);

    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

I still have no idea how to populate the whole ListView, Its just one TextView with alternate backgrounds. What i don't understand yet is how to set one row after another, haven't found a good example.

How can I resolve this? :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using just a single text field in your code you need not make a custom Adapter just for that as you can use Android's `ArrayAdapter`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listdata.toArray());

menu_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This snippet uses default Android List layout and a TextView which will take care of adding multiple rows for you.

**Edit:**
It looks like you need to use to use BaseAdapter for that you would need to make a class that extends BaseAdapter and use a ViewHolder, look at this blog which I wrote [androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in), it has a class which extends BaseAdapter and it uses a custom layout (.xml) file, you will get a basic idea of how its done

Comment: Right now yes, just a single textview but need to set alternate background colors. And probably other elements like images and buttons for other rows

Comment: For that you would need to make a class that extends BaseAdapter and use a ViewHolder, look at this blog which I wrote http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/, it has a class which extends BaseAdapter and it uses a custom layout (.xml) file, you will get a basic idea of how its done.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your issue, doing so will help others who have the same problem to quickly find the right answer.