# android: how can i read Jsonobject from custom list adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a JsonObject that I am trying to pass down to my CustomListView, I have read other threads on here similar to this but nothing is working. I have a simple JsonObject which produces this output

**{"localstreams":[{"people":"John","post":"My first post"}]}**

Which then I pass to my listview SetAdapter. The problem is that I get absolutely no errors and the activity shows up as blank eventhough I can see that it is forming the JsonObject. My code is easily reproducible and it is this..

**LocalFeed.Java**

```
     public class LocalFeed extends Activity
    {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.local_feed);
    try {
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.localfeed);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
        item.put("post", "My first post");
        item.put("people", "John");
        array.put(item);

        json.put("localstreams", array);



        DemoLocalFeed DMF=new DemoLocalFeed(json,this);
        lv.setAdapter(DMF);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("failed: "+ e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
      }
```

**The Activity associated with this is local_feed.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.exoler.LocalFeed"
        android:id="@+id/LocalFeed">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/localfeed"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

This is where my custom List Adapter is
    **DemoLocalFeed.java**

```
public class DemoLocalFeed extends BaseAdapter {

    JSONObject names;
    Context ctx;
LayoutInflater myiflater;
    public DemoLocalFeed(JSONObject arr,Context c)
    {
     ctx=c;
        names=arr;
        myiflater= (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        try {
            convertView = myiflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);
            TextView posts = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posts);
            TextView people= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.people);
            JSONArray  jArray = new JSONArray("localstreams");
   String postss="";
     String peoples="";
            for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            postss=  names.getString("post");
            peoples=  names.getString("people");
            }

            posts.setText(postss);
           people.setText(peoples);
            return convertView;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
return convertView;
 }
 }
```

**and it's activity customadapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000099"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/posts" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000099"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/people" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As stated before this does not give me an error it just shows up blank in the ListView by contrast if I change the **JsonObject into String[] then the ListView gets populated**. I have read other threads here on this topic such as [Android JSONObject to ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304684/android-jsonobject-to-listview) but can not get it working. I do think that I am close but can not seem to find out what is not working any suggestions would be great..

Comment: Made a mistake, try with the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
convertView = myiflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);
TextView posts = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posts);
TextView people= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.people);

JSONArray jaLocalstreams = names.getJSONArray("localstreams");
JSONObject jsonObject = jaLocalstreams.getJSONObject(position);
String postss = jsonObject.getString("post");
String peoples = jsonObject.getString("people");

posts.setText(postss);
people.setText(peoples);
```

Comment: Just tried it, it still showing up blank for some reason. I could not put in position like that since it expects a string so I put             **JSONObject jsonObject = names.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(position));**

Comment: @IgnacioPerez try the edit.. JSONObject jsonObject = jaLocalstreams.getJSONObject(position);